# Difference between Apache nifi and Apache Heron(Storm)

Tags: apache-storm, apache-nifi, heron

I'm working on a academic project which involves working on stream data from sensors. I've rounded on Heron(Successer of storm) and Nifi. Both have support for back pressure inbuilt which is crucial for my project.
What are the main differences between Apache Nifi and Heron?

Which one is more suitable for IoT applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell -

NiFi is more on the data acquisition from devices that supports several protocols while Heron is a stream processing engine that allows for complex streaming computations as data flows from NiFi. Heron can work along with NiFi in a single server as the footprint of Heron is smaller around 200 MB for local installation.

Answer (score 2):

It basically comes down to stream processing vs data flow...

I think this summarizes some of the differences:

[Difference between Apache Beam and Apache Nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231305/difference-between-apache-beam-and-apache-nifi)